# how to link radiobuttons with enumeration?

Tags: php, enumeration

im making a webshop to assemble your PC and i have radiobuttons for each part of the computer.

example:

```
<Form name ="formprocessor" Method ="Post" ACTION ="radioButton.php">
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='processor' value= 'b1'>Intel® Core™ i3 4130 3,4 GHzU</br>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='processor' value= 'b2'>Intel® Core™ i5 4670K 3.40 Ghz </br>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='processor' value= 'b2'>Intel® Core™ i7 4770K 3.5 GHz </br>

        </FORM>
```

now i dont know how to add enumeration to this form.

Comment: What's the PHP connection?

Comment: sorry im kind of a beginner to webdesign, i dont know what you mean with php connection

Comment: Well you tagged the question PHP, but there's no PHP in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of the form handler:-

```
// Get the submitted form data
$processor = $_POST['processor'];
$ram = $_POST['NAMEFORRAMHERE'];

// Connect to MySQL
$con = mysqli_connect("HOST","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

// Insert into database
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO cart (processorType, ram) VALUES ('$processor', '$ram')");
```

You can add in as many variables as you want, assuming that you are familiar with SQL. You should replace **NAMEFORRAMHERE** with the name of the radioButton group for RAM selection. Also, please note that you have to put inverted commas into the query if you want to use variables. For example, `'$processor'` and `'$ram'` as shown in the code above.

Good luck!

Comment: Thx for your comment, but i need to add the processor to my cart when it is checked. so how do i do it then?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I do not entirely understand your question.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see which radio button was picked after the form is submitted? @Dario

Comment: is it ok to give you a link to my page so you can see the example yourself? i have radiobuttons and when it is checked i want it to add to my shopping cart

Comment: Okay, sure. So basically, when I click the button it would automatically add it into the shopping cart?

Comment: i dont have a shopping cart yet because i dont really know how i link my radiobuttons to my Database products table

Comment: @Dario, you need to create the file you have stated in your ACTION field in the form tag. For this case, it's radioButton.php. In there, you can select variables to be used. For example, if you want to get the value of the processors radio button, you can do this:- `$variable = $_POST['processor'];` This will return to you the value of the selected processor. PHP POST variables depend on the name of the field, so if the radio button's `name` was 'processor2', you would use this instead: `$_POST['processor2']`

Comment: THX for the &reg; and the &trade; tip!

Comment: do you have an example how the radiobutton.php code looks like? sorry im kind of a noob at PHP. you are really helping me a lot!